# Unable to install windows azure SDK in windows phone 8 app

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, nuget, azure-storage

I am unable to install windows azure SDK on windows phone app from nuget .. I am getting the following message `Could not install package 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 2.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

I have seen tutorials with windows azure storage and windows phone http://tapanila.net/windows-azure-storage-sdk-now-supports-windows-phone-8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to install NuGet package for full .Net application. For `Windows 8`/`Windows Phone 8` application, there's another package you would need to install which is `Windows Azure Storage 3.0.2-preview` which you can install via Nuget Command Line using the following command:

```
Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage-Preview
```

Or look here for more instructions on installing this package: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-upload-data-blob-storage/ (scroll down to the section titled `Install the Storage client for Windows Store apps`).