# Compatibility issue while installing Windows azure storage in windows 8 app

Tags: azure, storage

I am facing compatibility issue when I am trying to install Windows Azure storage through nuget in my Windows 8 application.

Getting this error message:

> "You are trying to install this package into a project 
>   that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install windows azure SDK in windows phone 8 app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301077/unable-to-install-windows-azure-sdk-in-windows-phone-8-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While installing windowsazure.storage, make sure you have preview versions there as well.
Please see the following picture.

[image]